# How to store 36 bit image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a Raw Bayer image. Each channel(R,G and B) has bitdepth of 12. I would like to demosaic it and store it without losing the bitdepth in Matlab. How to store without losing the bitdepth?

Comment: is this image 3px big? (1x3 pixel)?

Comment: What do you mean by 3px big?

Comment: assert color depth = 12 bits/pixel => 36bits / [12bits/pixel] = 3pixel

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a 36 Bit image! The standard way of storing it is to Store as 16-Bit image format. So 16*3= 48 Bits e.g you can store it in .png format!

e.g

[`imwrite(A,'myImage.png');`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)

Comment: Storing it as  16 bits is also fine for me.. In Matlab they mentioned as demosaiced image will be stored as true color image(24 bit). So how to store as 48 bit image.

Comment: But to View that you may need a 16-Bit image viewer which will scale down the image to 8 bits. Otherwise you can directly convert it into a 8 bit image and then save!